# How to use ScientificForm in computation

Tags: functions, formatting

Lets say I want to add 2 values :

```
ScientificForm[Quantity[0.6884806137833915, "Millimeters"], 2] + 
   ScientificForm[Quantity[0.0629737394087381, "Millimeters"], 2]
```

To get result

```
ScientificForm[Quantity[0.75, "Millimeters"], 2]
```

Edit:

Small example, it seems more complicated because context and comments are lost. Idea here is, to get formula first and then after adding input data I get the values also. This works, but I want to keep only 2-3 most significant digits - here is where ScientificForm seems to be inapplicable.

[image]

Source:

```
l = a/b (Overscript[Subscript[s, 1], _] - 
     Overscript[Subscript[s, 2], _]);
m["Subscript[U, c](Overscript[l, _])"] = 
 Sqrt[(D[l, a] m["Subscript[U, C](a)"])^2 + (D[l, b] m[
       "Subscript[U, C](b)"])^2 + (D[l, 
       Overscript[Subscript[s, 1], _]] m[
       "Subscript[U, C](Subscript[s, 1])"])^2 + (D[l, 
       Overscript[Subscript[s, 2], _]] m[
       "Subscript[U, C](Subscript[s, 2])"])^2]
a = Subscript[na, 1] - Subscript[na, 2];
b = Subscript[nb, 1] - Subscript[nb, 2];
m["Subscript[U, C](b)"] = 
 m["Subscript[U, C](a)"] = 
  Sqrt[(m["Subscript[U, c](Subscript[na, 1])"]*
       D[a, {Subscript[na, 1]}])^2 + (m[
        "Subscript[U, c](Subscript[na, 2])"]*
       D[a, {Subscript[na, 2]}])^2]
m["Subscript[U, C](Subscript[s, 2])"] = 
 m["Subscript[U, C](Subscript[s, 1])"] = (Sqrt[(Subscript[
         t, \[Infinity], \[Beta]] Subscript[e, p, kruvik]/
         3)^2 + (\[Beta] Subscript[L, kruvik])^2])
m["Subscript[U, c](Subscript[nb, 2])"] = 
 m["Subscript[U, c](Subscript[nb, 1])"] = 
  m["Subscript[U, c](Subscript[na, 2])"] = 
   m["Subscript[U, c](Subscript[na, 1])"] = 
    Sqrt[(Subscript[
          t, \[Infinity], \[Beta]] Subscript[e, p, joonlaud]/
          3)^2 + (\[Beta] Subscript[L, joonlaud])^2]
\[Beta](*usaldatavus*)= 0.95;
Subscript[
   t, \[Infinity], \[Beta]](*studenti tegur*)= \
\!\(TraditionalForm\`Round[
     InverseCDF[StudentTDistribution[10000], \[Beta]], 0.1]\);
Subscript[t, v, \[Beta]]= 
  Round[InverseCDF[StudentTDistribution[v], \[Beta]], 0.1];
Subscript[e, p, kruvik]= 
  Quantity[0.004, "Millimeters"];
Subscript[L, kruvik]= 
  Quantity[0.005, "Millimeters"];
Subscript[L, joonlaud]= 
  Quantity[0.5, "Millimeters"];
Subscript[e, p, joonlaud]= 
  Quantity[0.2, "Millimeters"];
a = Subscript[na, 1] - Subscript[na, 2];
b = Subscript[nb, 1] - Subscript[nb, 2];
a = Quantity[0.78, "Meters"]; 
b = Quantity[0.112, "Meters"]; 
Subscript[s, 1] = {Quantity[3.67, "Millimeters"], 
   Quantity[3.63, "Millimeters"], Quantity[3.65, "Millimeters"], 
       Quantity[3.65, "Millimeters"]}; 
Subscript[s, 2] = {Quantity[2.82, "Millimeters"], 
   Quantity[2.8, "Millimeters"], Quantity[2.8, "Millimeters"], 
       Quantity[2.8, "Millimeters"]}; 
Overscript[Subscript[s, 1], _] = Mean[Subscript[s, 1]];
Overscript[Subscript[s, 2], _] = Mean[Subscript[s, 2]];
m["Subscript[U, c](Overscript[l, _])"]
m["Subscript[U, C](Subscript[s, 2])"]
m["Subscript[U, C](b)"]
m["Subscript[U, c](Subscript[nb, 2])"]
```

Comment: Do you want to keep all expressions in ScientificForm[]?  The computation works if we do e.g.     `n1 = ScientificForm[Quantity[0.6884806137833915, "Millimeters"], 2];
    n2 = ScientificForm[Quantity[0.0629737394087381, "Millimeters"], 2];  
    ScientificForm[First@n1 + First@n2, 2]`

Comment: Do you want to keep all expressions in ScientificForm[]? Yes.

Computation does not work in my case, where i first compute the formula and then answer. I use variable 'm' as hashmap to store unified errors in scientific form and function First would be applied in formula computation. I could probably use HoldForm / ReleaseHold, but that would create a layer of extra complexity.

Comment: Could you expand your question with the above information and a minimal example of this behaviour?  That is, define a (shortened) hash map and show the kind of operation you're attempting, and the output you're getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to first do:

```
 $Post = Function[n, n /. Quantity[r_?NumberQ , unit_] :> 
                          Quantity[ScientificForm[r, 2], unit]];
```

Then

```
 Quantity[0.6884806137833915, "Millimeters"] + 
 Quantity[0.0629737394087381, "Millimeters"]
```

results in

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and also your small example works.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to style all numbers with `ScientificForm` you should proceed as Rolf Mertig shows, but if you only want to affect a specific set of objects you could use UpValues, perhaps like this:

```
With[{SF = ScientificForm},
  Unprotect[SF];
  Scan[
    (#[SF[a_, n1_], SF[b_, n2_], c___] ^:= SF[a ~#~ b, Max[n1, n2]] ~#~ c) &,
    {Plus, Times, Power}
  ]
  Protect[SF];
]
```